# Why I am not able to connect to the database

Tags: python-3.x, class, sqlite

```
import lot_details, car_details
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('parkingLot.db')
c = conn.cursor()

class Parking(object):


    """
    Parking class which has details about parking slots
    as well as operation performed on parking are present here
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.slots = {}

    def create_parking_lot(self, no_of_slots):

        try:
            c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parkingTable(slot_no REAL, reg_no TEXT, colour TEXT, total_time TEXT,charge TEXT)')
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Couldn't make a table in DB")
        no_of_slots = int(no_of_slots)

        if len(self.slots) > 0:
            print ("Parking Lot already created")
            return

        if no_of_slots > 0:
            for i in range(1, no_of_slots+1):
                temp_slot = lot_details.PSlot(slot_no=i, available=True)
                self.slots[i] = temp_slot
            print ("Created a parking lot with {} slots" .format(no_of_slots))
        else:
            print ("Number of slots provided is incorrect.")
        return
```

Using above code I am trying to create a database(which is successful) but now I am not able to create the Table inside it using the above command.
I tried doing it separately its working there. But, I am not able to create it using above code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how and where you are creating the `Parking` object I suspect this could be a scoping issue, either pass the db connection into the constructor or just create it in the constructor itself. Code modified for brevity. The following works for me.

```
import sqlite3

class Parking(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.slots = {}
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('parkingLot.db')

    def create_parking_lot(self, no_of_slots):

        try:
            cur = self.conn.cursor()
            cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parkingTable(slot_no REAL, reg_no TEXT, colour TEXT, total_time TEXT,charge TEXT)')
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Couldn't make a table in DB")

        return

parking = Parking()
parking.create_parking_lot(5)
```